# matching patterns and create new files

Tags: csv, awk, grep

I have a csv file named file1.csv:

```
something;AD;sss;Andorra;nothing;type_1;sss
something222;AD;sss222;Andorra;nothing222;type_2;aaa
thing;NL;thing3;Netherlands;thing;type_2;bb
etc;US;etc;United States;etc;type_2;nothing
```

I want  to create separate files for each country. I make greps like that:

```
grep -e "\;AD\;.*\;Andorra\;" file1.csv > fileAD.csv
grep -e "\;NL\;.*\;Netherlands\;" file1.csv > fileNL.csv
grep -e "\;US\;.*\;United\sStates\;" file1.csv > fileUS.csv
```

This works, but I have all countries in the world. And i don't want to write these lines for every country. Is there any other solution ? Any help is really apreciated.

Edit: I updated my question. I also have a column with type_1 and type_2. And after all the files corresponding each country are created , I need to create new files for every country with just type_1 and new files with just type_2.

For example, for Andorra, I need the files:
fileAD.csv :

```
something;AD;sss;Andorra;nothing;type_1;sss
something222;AD;sss222;Andorra;nothing222;type_2;aaa
```

fileADtype_1.csv:

```
something;AD;sss;Andorra;nothing;type_1;sss
```

fileADtype_2.csv:

```
something222;AD;sss222;Andorra;nothing222;type_2;aaa
```

I think that is ok to look just for the column with the abbreviation, but i wanted the 2 columns, the one with "AD" and the one with the full_name "Andorra" for security reasons.

Comment: @Sundeep , thank you. I updated my question. Your response works. I think it's fine, i don't think 2 countries can have the same abbreviation. I hope this not happen. I also need to break the fileAD.csv into 2 more files corresponding the column with types.

Comment: @Savas31 changing requirements is not encouraged because answers already given need to be updated.. so, I advice to revert the question to previous state, but add the clarification that full name need not be matched... for your extra steps, you should be able to work it out yourself from the answers given

Comment: @Sundeep, sorry , i didn 't figure it out how this works here..i'm new. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I go for a one liner with only one instance of `awk`, without temporary files:

```
awk -F ';' '{print >> "file" $2 ".csv"}' file1.csv
```

Comment: thanks, this works. It is possible to obtain in some way all the files fileAD.csv , fileADtype_1.csv and fileADtype_2.csv ?  Or just fileADtype_1.csv and fileADtype_2.csv ?

Comment: Yes, this is also possible, with `awk -F ';' '{print >> "file" $2 $6 ".csv"}' file1.csv`, and if you want both in one shot, you can combine these by doing: `awk -F ';' '{print >> "file" $2 ".csv"; print >> "file" $2 $6 ".csv"}' file1.csv`.

Comment: Is there a way to specify a path for the output files ? To write a path after the 'print >>' ?

Comment: @Savas31: of course. Just issue `print >> "path/to/file" $2 ".csv"`.

Answer (score 2):

As one liner with `awk`:

```bash
for code in $(awk -F';' '{print $2}' data.csv | uniq); do awk -F';' -v pat="$code" '$2 ~ pat {print $0}' data.csv > "file${code}.csv"; done
```